# Game time card - how does it work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When I buy a [SWTOR Game Time Card](http://www.swtor.com/gametimecard), what exactly does 60 days of game time mean, and how it is tied to the real world time? I have read all FAQs and subscriptions, but I am still none the wiser.

- Does it mean I can play a game 60 days since I redeem the code, like when redeemed on January 1, I can play until March 1?
- Or does it mean any day I play one day is deduced from the game time, but I can have days which I do not play in between?
- Or does it mean I can spend 60*24 hours in the game, no matter how the real world calendar runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the 60 day game time card, it means that once redeemed you will have 60 days of game time. This is calculated based on when you redeemed your card, so using your examples above it would be this one:

*Does it mean I can play a game 60 days since I redeem the code, like when redeemed on Janunary 1, I can play until March 1?*

Comment: Well, you can play until March 2; unless it's a leap year :-)

Comment: true story, I didn't even bother working that out :P

Comment: So I guess statistically speaking, you could play until March 1.75 :-)

Comment: @Flater - 60 days is 1,440 hours exactly.  That is how long you have to play with a 60 day game time.